# NSFilemanager attributesOfItemAtPath frustrations

Tags: objective-c

I'm using a bit of code that a user posted here modified for my settings to do a file copy with a progress bar (from Cocoa is my Girlfriend http://www.cimgf.com/2008/05/03/cocoa-tutorial-file-copy-with-progress-indicator/ ).

I have attempted to fix some of the use of deprecated methods and in the process have broken detecting file size. I spent most of the day yesterday trying different things to fix it but haven't had any luck. I should also note that sourceFilePath is obtained from a NSTextField.

I know the error message says the file doesn't exist but it certainly does. It's path doesn't contain any sym links and to be sure I used the NSString method stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath. Any ideas what's going wrong here? Here's the code, and the error message I get.

```
- (IBAction)startCopy:(id)sender;
{
NSError *attributeserror = nil;

NSString *accountsourcestring = [sourceFilePath stringValue];
NSString *accountsourcestringpath =[accountsourcestring stringByStandardizingPath];

// Use the NSFileManager to obtain the size of our source file in bytes.
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary *sourceAttributes = [fileManager     attributesOfItemAtPath:accountsourcestringpath error:&attributeserror];
NSNumber *sourceFileSize= [sourceAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
long long fileSize = [sourceFileSize longLongValue];

NSLog(@"Filesize = %lld", fileSize);
NSLog(@"sourcefilepath: %@", accountsourcestring);

if ((sourceFileSize = [sourceAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize]) )
{
    // Set the max value to our source file size
    [progressIndicator setMaxValue:(double)[sourceFileSize unsignedLongLongValue]];
}
    else
{
    // Couldn't get the file size so we need to bail.
    NSLog(@"Unable to obtain size of file being copied. Error %@ Source file size: %@,   sourceAttributes: %@", attributeserror, sourceFileSize, sourceAttributes);
    return;
}
```

And here's the error message logged in console:

```
2012-09-01 11:23:07.061 Copy File[1004:303] Filesize = 0
2012-09-01 11:23:07.062 Copy File[1004:303] sourcefilepath:     file://localhost/Users/daniel/Lion%20plists/
2012-09-01 11:23:07.072 Copy File[1004:303] Unable to obtain size of file being copied.    Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Lion%20plists” couldn’t be opened   because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x100173770   {NSFilePath=file:/localhost/Users/daniel/Lion%20plists, NSUnderlyingError=0x100140240 "The   operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"} Source file size: (null),   sourceAttributes: (null)
```

Comment: For variable names and for the sake of readability, it is recommented toUseCamelCaps...

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm in the habbit of not camelcaps and it's hard to break. :-(

Comment: Your `sourcefilepath` contains percent escapes ("%20"), so you should use `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` to remove that.

Comment: Also your path looks more like a directory.

Comment: Your code needs some cleanup. Remove all unneeded occurences of `*` in `NSString *` `NSDictionary *` `NSNumber *` etc and dive into object oriented programming.

Comment: It looks like you're passing a string containing a URL to a method expecting a path. The value of the string should look like "/Users/daniel/Lion plists/", instead of "file://localhost/Users/daniel/Lion%20plists/".